# Not-permanently change column type in snowflake

Tags: sql, types, geometry, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, varchar

I have view in snowfflake.
Currently, one of the columns is geography type and it I cannot run any query on the dataset due to invalid geometry.
I want to change the type of the specific column to varchar just in order to load the data, without permanently change it.
I have tried to use ALTER_TABLE :

```
ALTER TABLE "TABLES"."FBN"."TABLE" ALTER COLUMN "GEOMETRY" TYPE VARCHAR
```

but seems like that suppose to change data permanently, as I get error that I don't have privileges to operate this:

```
SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on view 'TABLE'
```

I want to change the type of  data just when I read the table so I can download the data and after that fix the geoemtry.
**My end goal here is to change column type no permanently so I can read the data.**

Comment: Can you create this as a View over the table rather than trying to alter the table? By the way, calling a table "TABLE" is a really bad design decision

Comment: the name table is in this example is because I changed it for the example

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance to use predicate pushdown to make it work:

```
SELECT *
FROM view_name
WHERE TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY("GEOMETRY") IS NOT NULL;
-- WHERE TRY_TO_GEOGRAPHY("GEOMETRY"::VARIANT) IS NOT NULL;
```